# How to change response of BearerTokenServerAuthenticationEntryPoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security to authenticate with oauth2. It is working correctly returning a 401 Unauthorized. The body is empty though, and I am wondering if it is possible to just change this portion. I am using Webflux, so I know I can create my own authenticationEntryPoint, but I don't want that as [BearerTokenServerAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/server/BearerTokenServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) works. Is there a way to just change the response in Spring without creating my own custom class?